# Failed to run exposed service on MacBook Pro M1

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I try to run an exposed service on my Macbook(M1). However, I failed to browse the service locally. What could be the root cause?
Please see the attached images.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What service do you use? LoadBalancer, NodePort, ClusterIP?

Comment: @RafałLeszko - NodePort.

Comment: There is a similar question with the same error which can be helpful. Can you please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62375642/minikube-ip-returns-127-0-0-1-kubernetes-nodeport-service-not-accessable)  and confirm?

Comment: @BakulMitra - thank you for sharing the link. However, I tried the solution mentioned in the link it still failed. The browser gets popped up but still can't access the service with the IP and port. I'm wondering what could be the issue?

Comment: Hello @David, Are you still facing the problem? Was your problem resolved? Was my answer helpful. If you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it (✔️). I'd really appreciate it. Have a great day, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is the shortcut command for fetching the minikube IP and a service’s NodePort not working?

```sh
minikube service --url <service-name>
```

Comment: Are you asking or providing a solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are some limitations with minikube running with docker driver on MacOS. Please see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11193#issuecomment-826331511).

There are two options at least (more, but these are simple to do):

- use the minikube tunnel

[Tunnel](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/tunnel/) is used to expose the service from inside of the VM where minikube is running to the host machine's network. Please refer to [access applications in minikube.](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/)

This is how `minikube_IP:NodePort` transforms to `localhost:different_port`.

- start minikube with VirtualBox driver to get a proper IP (if you
  really need to access your service on NodePort), below the command
  how to start it with VirtualBox driver (this should be installed on
  your machine):

  ```
    minikube start --driver=VirtualBox
  ```